# MySQL Many-to-Many Select across 4 tables

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, one-to-many

I need a SELECT query will work for both a many-to-many and one-to-many relationship. Here is what I mean:

I have 5 tables.

```
-Groups-
groupId | groupName
12 | Some Group


-users-
userId | userName
5 | SomeGuy
6 | SomeoneElse


-linker-
groupId | userID
12 | 5
12 | 6


-votes-
userid | votingUser | groupId
6 | 5 | 12


-comments-
commentId | groupId | userId | commentValue
45 | 12 | 5 | "SomeGuy said something"
```

I am trying to select all the groups, all the users, count the votes, and select the 2 latest comments.

Basically, the idea is that users can vote on users in a group and also comment on a group. I have a feeling this is simpler than I'm making it, but at the moment I'm finding it a bit overwhelming.

Perhaps it is best to simply split this into multiple queries?

I appreciate any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: how many group is the user allowed to join?

Comment: A user can join any number of groups. Sorry if the relationships are a bit confusing...

Comment: Can you please explain the `votes` table? what is the difference between `userid` and votinguser` id? and why there is a `groupid` in this table since the userid should be related to a group in another table not in the votes table.

Comment: i think you are trying to do multiple task in one query, but i think it would be better if you create different functions for for getting comments, getting number of votes and getting users in group, it will make your functions reusable.

Comment: Good point about reusable code, Philip. Unless I find a better solution I am splitting up the query.

Comment: Mahmoud, `userid` is the user `votingUser` voted for. `groupid` is necessary because the vote only applies to that group. In other words, a user may have 10 votes in one group and 8 votes in another. Basically an election type of system.